Do we always use the Hamiltonian operator in solving for the wavefunction of a chemical system? If so, why not some other operator?
As I understand it, in order to obtain the wavefunction for a system we solve the eigenvalue equation for the Hamiltonian:
$$\hat{H}\psi=E\psi$$
The wavefunction obtained contains all the information about the system. Observable properties of the system will be returned by applying an appropriate operator according to the eigenvalue equation:
$$\hat{A}\psi=a \psi$$
[ed: where A is a QM operator and a an observable of the operator].
Of course this assumes that psi is an eigenvector of the operator. That all makes sense to me.
My question: is there any reason why we MUST use solutions to the Hamiltonian eigenvalue equation as our wavefunctions? Could we instead solve the eigenvalue equation for some other operator to obtain our wavefunctions? And would these wavefunctions be somehow invalid, or contain less information than those obtained using the Hamiltonian?
Using the Hamiltonian to find (psi) does make sense to me since we can encode the description of our particular system within the potential energy operator, but I'm not sure that this answers my question. I also understand the importance of the Hamiltonian in terms of time dependence and that solving the TDSE tells us about changes in the wavefunction with time, but then that is not important for stable states.

We use the Dirac equation (or DCB equation) and operators related to QED for more accurate results. I would write a more detailed answer at Matter Moeling Stack Exchange since I'm not active here anymore, but someone else might reply to you here.

@user1271772 the question is on-topic here and you are welcome to post an answer.

It's a good question that would be wasted at matter modelling in my opinion.

The hamiltonian represents the total energy, kinetic+potential so its a sensible thing to use.  However, the Schroedinger equation has no proper derivation, and its only through agreement with experiments what we can justify using it. There is still an argument as to how to interpret the wavefunction. You need to ask on the physics stack exchange site to get more on this.

Any quantum mechanical problem can be cast into linear algebra form. This is, actually, the prime methods for solving quantum chemistry problems. In this case, Hamiltonian an can be represented as a doubly infinite matrix. To produce same results when used to obtain eigen vector (and wave-function when said vector is cast back into function space), an operator should have the same eigen-vectors (barring complications coming because of degenerate eigen-vectors). This actually is routinely used for solving big eigenvector/eigenvalue problems. So, any operator with same eigenvectors should work. The problem is that constructing such operator without obtaining eigen-vectors beforehand isn't trivial. One such operator is lagrangian, dual to hamiltonian in the sense that it uses velocities instead of momenta.
To provide background on relation of lagrangian and hamiltonian. When Newton first published his view on mechanics, it was done in a very inconvenient geometric formulation. So, people tried to make it easier to work with. Eventually they came to idea of formulation using concepts of function and derivative (Newton claimed to know it too, but considered inferior for ideological reasons). But this form worked in Cartesian coordinates. Sometimes it makes sense to use other coordinates. So, people looked for more generic formulations and eventually came for Lagrangian analytical mechanics, formulated in terms of generic coordinates. A bit later a complimentary formulation emerged, known as Hamiltonian mechanics. The difference was that Lagrange used velocities, while Hamilton used momenta. In both cases the core concept was principle of minimal action: an action integral should be minimized. An action integral is an operator acting over a function representing trajectory.
So, there are at least two operators that provide absolutely identical results in classical mechanics. The wave function is a quantum mechanical equivalent of trajectory in classical mechanics, so this should translate into quantum mechanics as well. I never looked into details, but quick googling shows that Lagrange approach IS used in some situations.

In principle, you can use any operator you wish, provided they have simultaneous eigenfunctions. In fact, there are entire textbooks that shift the focus from energetics to other properties. The key point is that, since typical quantum chemistry operators are linear and Hermitian, their eigenstates are generally not unique. Up to a linear combination of eigenstates, it’s always possible to construct another solution for the eigenvalue problem. This means that, in general, it's often more insightful to focus on observables rather than specific eigenvectors. Observables can be obtained by calculating eigenvalues of certain operators, or by computing expectation values when proper eigenfunctions are not available.
Why, then, is the Hamiltonian so important?
First, the Hamiltonian governs the energetics of the system, and knowing the energetics usually allows us to infer many other properties of the system.
This first fact, coupled to us chemists usually needing to know only the ground state of our system and thus only the lowest eigenpair of the Hamiltonian, is the key point to why the Hamiltonian approach is the most diffused.
Secondly, it’s crucial to note that the eigenstates of different operators are not always the same. For example, the linear momentum operator does not commute with the Hamiltonian in cases where the potential is not translationally invariant, such as in the field of atomic nuclei.
This means that their eigenfunctions are NOT simultaneous. $$[\hat{H},\hat{p}]=\hat{H}\hat{p}-\hat{p}\hat{H}=-i{\hbar}\nabla V(\mathbf{r})$$
Also, consider that we are particularly interested in the stability of molecules and their transformations, so we primarily use the Hamiltonian to gain insights into these aspects. While it's true that we can visualize the eigenstates as isodensities when solving approximate Hamiltonians for molecules, allowing us to create graphical representations, this does not imply that these eigenstates are the "correct" ones to consider for every property.
From a technical standpoint, it's also important to note that the Hamiltonian serves as the generator of infinitesimal time translations. This becomes evident when studying operators within the Heisenberg, Schrödinger, and Dirac pictures of quantum mechanics. Consequently, beyond the linear algebra associated with the operator itself, the Hamiltonian holds a more profound, central role in the theory.

"the Hamiltonian governs the energetics of the system, and knowing the energetics usually allows us to infer many other properties of the system" coupled with us usually having to know the lowest energy state, hence lowest eigenpair of the Hamiltonian, before we can do much more is to me the key point

This surely is a key point, I will make an edit and stress this more!
